# Trouble implementing slidedown() animation on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get my header navbar to slide down upon a user's visit to my webpage, but I must be doing something wrong because my function isn't registering, thus resulting in the navbar appearing in its entirety from the get-go.

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pHZuzw77up).

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a id="tab1" href="#">Text</a></li>

                    </ul><!-- END: "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" -->
                </div><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.navbar-inverse').slideDown(1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this:

DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/WOXmGk0wqF

Add Class SlideIn (or whatever you want to call it):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top slideIn">
```

CSS

```
.slideIn {
    top:-100px;
}

.navbar {transition:all 1s ease-in-out}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.navbar-inverse').removeClass('slideIn');
```

Comment: Wow, this is even better. Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, even though this code works on Bootply, it doesn't work on my personal webpage, any my code doesn't at all differ. Why could this be?

Comment: probably because you need to add the .slideIn class after all other css because the fixed position already has a top position it's going to over ride the .slideIn class because it's specific.

Comment: Even with all my JS and CSS, it still works in Bootply but not on my page. I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: And the .slideIn class is after your bootstrap css?

Comment: Yeah, but it's position in my Bootply CSS makes no difference - it works regardless.

Comment: The bootply css is after the bootstrap.css, so it will work, if it's not after the bootstrap.css in your actual site, it won't work.

Comment: Ugh, this is frustrating. Is there any other way to simulate this animation? Thanks for your time to reply, btw.

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work without looking at your site. Did you actually put the class after your bootstrap css.

Comment: Yes, I've done everything. I've also **strictly** used the css you provided, and still no success.

Comment: Wait, whoa. I just saw it work, but it went by so quickly. Is there any way to delay the animation?

Comment: transition-delay: 2s;

Comment: Every time you do something clear your browser cache

Comment: Ah, yeah. There we go. Smh, lol. Thank you for everything. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4):

You should change `min-height` property of navbar to `0`
http://www.bootply.com/bGD3AAUds4